# how can i convert this sql to sequelize funciton

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

i wanna to convert sql to sequelize function

i tried code

```
const result = await models.chapter.findOne({
    logging: log.trace,
    where: {
      seq: db.fn('max', db.col('seq'))
    }
  });
```

success code in sql
`select * from page_chapter where seq = (select max(seq) from page_chapter)`

i expect the result like

```
  const result = await model.chapter.findOne({
    where: {
      seq: sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('seq'))
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your query by using `sequelize.literal` :

```
const result = await model.chapter.findOne({
    where: sequelize.literal('"seq" = (SELECT MAX("page_chapter"."seq") FROM "page_chapter")')
})
```

Comment: sorry man, i tried the code, but error happend. SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "FROM". my tools: sequelize 4.8.0.

Comment: I had forgotten an ending parenthesis on the SELECT MAX(...). I edited my answer

Comment: thanks,a lot.actually, i wanna tried to edit you comment, then i found the right ),iafter "seq".so i confused.HAHA...

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query directly using `sequelize.query`.

```
const result = await sequelize.query(`
  SELECT * 
  FROM page_chapter 
  WHERE seq = (
    SELECT max(seq) 
    FROM page_chapter
  )
`, { model: models.chapter });
```

OR you can break down the query into the two parts

```
const maxSeq = await models.chapter.max('seq');
const result = await models.chapter.findOne({
  where: {
    seq: maxSeq
  }
});
```